# Shape derivative at manifold $M$ in direction $v$ is equal to the shape derivative at $\partial M$ in drection $\langle v,n\rangle n$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-equations, oc.optimization-and-control, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let $\tau>0$ and $d\in\mathbb N$.

**Definiton 1**$\:\:\:$If $v:[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ with $v(\;\cdot\;,x)\in C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$ and $$\sup_{t\in[0,\:\tau]}\left\|v(t,x)-v(t,y)\right\|\le c_1\left\|x-y\right\|\tag1$$ for some $c_1\ge0$, then there is a unique $X^x\in C^0([0,\tau],\mathbb R^d)$ with $$X^x(t)=x+\int_0^tv(s,X^x(s))\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau].$$ Moreover, $$T^{(v)}_t(x):=X^x(t)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d$$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism for all $t\in[0,\tau]$. Let $\mathcal V$ denote the set of all such $v$.

Now let $\mathcal F:2^{\mathbb R^d}\to\mathbb R$.

**Definiton 2**$\:\:\:$If $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ and $v\in\mathcal V$, then $\mathcal F$ is called *shape differentiable* at $\Omega$ in direction $v$ if $$[0,\tau]\ni t\mapsto\mathcal F\left(T^{(v)}_t(\Omega)\right)\tag2$$ is differentiable at $0$. In that case, $${\rm d}\mathcal F(\Omega;v):=\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{\mathcal F\left(T^{(v)}_t(\Omega)\right)-\mathcal F(\Omega)}t.$$

Let $M$ be a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary and $\nu_{\partial M}$ denote the unique outward pointing unit normal field on $\partial M$. We can show that if $v\in\mathcal V$ with $$\langle\left.v\right|_{[0,\:\tau]\times\partial M},\nu_{\partial M}\rangle=0\tag3,$$ then $$T_t^{(v)}(\partial M)=\partial M\tag4.$$ From this result we can infer that $$T_t^{(v)}(M)=M\tag5.$$

> Now let $v\in\mathcal V$ be arbitrary and $\tilde\nu\in C^0(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$ be any extension of $\nu_{\partial M}$. I would like to show that, if $\mathcal F$ is shape differentiable at $M$ in direction $v$, then $\mathcal F$ is shape differentiable at $\partial M$ in direction $u:=\langle v,\tilde\nu\rangle\tilde\nu$ and $${\rm d}\mathcal F(M,v)={\rm d}\mathcal F(\partial M,u)\tag6.$$

I'm not sure what the best approach is. We may note that $$T^{(u)}_t(\langle x,\tilde\nu(x)\rangle\tilde\nu(x))=\langle T^{(v)}_t(x),\tilde\nu(x)\rangle\tilde\nu(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }(t,x)\in[0,\tau]\times\mathbb R^d\tag7.$$ Or we may consider $w:=v-u$ and note $$\langle\left.w\right|_{[0,\:\tau]\times\partial M},\nu_{\partial M}\rangle=0\tag8,$$ which implies $T_t^{(w)}(\partial M)=\partial M$ and $T_t^{(w)}(M)=M$ by the former result.

### EDIT

The following example might clarify what I'm trying to achieve. Assume $$\mathcal F(\Omega)=\lambda^{\otimes d}(\Omega)\;\;\;\text{for all }\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)\tag9,$$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$. Let $\Omega\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$, $v\in\mathcal V$ and assume that $$\det{\rm DT^{(v)}_t}>0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\delta)\tag{10}$$ for some $\delta>0$. We then obtain $$\left.\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\mathcal F\left(T^{(v)}_t(\Omega)\right)\right|_{t=0}=\int_\Omega\left.\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\det{\rm D}T^{(v)}_t\right|_{t=0}{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}=\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot v_0\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}\tag{11},$$ where I wrote $v_0:=v(0,\;\cdot\;)$. If now $\Omega$ is a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, we can write $$\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot v_0\:{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}=\int\langle v_0,\nu_{\partial\Omega}\rangle\:{\rm d}\sigma_{\partial\Omega}\tag{12},$$ where $\sigma_{\partial\Omega}$ denotes the surface measure on $\mathcal B(\partial\Omega)$. What I'm trying to obtain is a generalization of this result as described in the question.

Comment: If I'm understanding your setup correctly, (8) can't be true in general. For example, if $\mathcal F$ is $d$-dimensional volume, then $\mathcal F(\partial M)$ is always zero, and thus the right-hand side of (8) is always zero. (Of course, volume is not defined for arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb R^d$. But you could replace it by inner measure or outer measure, and the same comment would apply.)

Comment: @JackLee (8) does not depend on $\mathcal F$. Did you really mean (8)?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been (6).

Comment: @JackLee Well, from your example, it seems like something is wrong here. This is supposed to be a simplified version of "Hadamard's theorem". Please take a look at Propostion 2.26 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=bkruCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22is+included+in+the+kernel+of+the+continuous%22&source=bl&ots=3PnvrA9Zpk&sig=ACfU3U1FHf6mfnaEU338SZEoTMLFTs42Vw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEtdnSkdDrAhVI_qQKHT1gDxoQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20included%20in%20the%20kernel%20of%20the%20continuous%22&f=true). The claim there should be more or less the same as in the quesiton.

Comment: @JackLee I've added the example you've mentioned to the question. Hopefully it's clearer now what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @JackLee Maybe I'm misunderstanding the claim made in Proposition 2.26. Maybe it's only claiming that there exists a functional $\varphi(\partial M,\;\cdot\;)$ on a space of functions $\partial M\to\mathbb R$ such that $${\rm d}\mathcal F(M,v)=\varphi(\partial M,u)\tag{6'}.$$ To be honest, this is the claim literally made, but denoting $\varphi(\partial M,\;\cdot\;)$ by ${\rm d}\mathcal F(\partial M,\;\cdot\;)$ is highly confusing and obviously ambigiuous.